# What is faithful$waiting in RShiny?

Tags: r, shiny

I'm new to Rshiny, could you please explain me what does faithful$waiting mean in the following code ?

```
server <- function(input, output) {
  
output$distPlot <- renderPlot({
   
 x    <- faithful$waiting
    bins <- seq(min(x), max(x), length.out = input$bins + 1)

    hist(x, breaks = bins, col = "#007bc2", border = "white",
         xlab = "Waiting time to next eruption (in mins)",
         main = "Histogram of waiting times")

    })
}
```

Many thanks!!

Comment: It's nothing to do with Shiny really. `faithful` is a data frame and `waiting` is one of its columns. The Shiny part is `input$bins`, where the user selects the number of bins for a histogram plot.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your comment, as I don't see the datafram "faithful" defined a priori, can I consider it the "underlined" datafram of Shiny package ? or there must be some inititation of the dataframe somewhere else ? Thanks!!

Comment: The dataset is included in R, see `https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/datasets/html/faithful.html` and `https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/datasets/html/00Index.html`
Those datasets can always be used without declaration.